# How to get accumulated historical data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am here to ask about how exactly the cumulative sum() works.

I consider, starting from the previous 900 bar to the recent last bar, to sum.
before 900 bar, I would like to exclude data.
such as from the previous 900th bar = 0 or first volume and would like to cumulate it to the last one.
so back from the 901st bar, not considered.

But when I use normal math.sum(volume,900), all data is continuously summed.

```
a1 = close>open?volume:0
b1 = math.sum(a1,900)
plot(b1)
```